# buffer zone for polygon in matlab

Tags: matlab, buffer, polygon

I would like to create a buffer zone for the given simple polygon (no convex, no holes) in matlab without using bufferm function.

```
vx = [ 2 4 6 4 2]; %  polygon vertices
vy = [ 2 4 3 2 2];
figure;
% axis equal;
plot([vx vx(1)],[vy vy(1)],'r');
hold on;
vx = vx(end:-1:1); % Vertices in cw direction
vy = vy(end:-1:1);
xctr = mean(vx(1:end-1)); % find centroid of polygon
yctr = mean(vy(1:end-1));
sf = 2; % scale factor to extend polygon
rx = vx - xctr; % find radius
ry = vy - yctr;
angle = atand(ry/rx); % find angle
new_vx = xctr + rx * cosd(angle) * sf; % find new vertex at a distance of sf
new_vy = yctr + ry * sind(angle) * sf;
plot([new_vx new_vx(1)],[new_vy new_vy(1)], 'g');
```

But it plots wrongly. Any ideas pls..

Comment: Do you want receive buffer zone with fixed width? Why there is no width value?

Comment: i have given it as sf=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change angle to

```
angle = atan2(ry,rx);
```

new_vx to

```
new_vx = xctr + abs(rx) .* cos(angle) * sf;
```

and new_vy to either

```
new_vy = yctr + abs(ry) .* sin(angle) * sf;
```

or

```
new_vy = yctr + ry * sf;
```

depending on how you want it to look.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have several problems in code.

The first is angle calculation. Atand function return result in range from -90 to 90. Therefore, you will have problems with points in second and third quadrant. It is better to use construction like:

```
ang = angle(rx + ry*1i)
```

The second problem in incorrect use of sf. Your construction

```
new_vx = xctr + rx * cosd(angle) * sf;
```

use sf as scaling factor, but not as distance. Really, you need plus between rx and cosd, e.g.

```
new_vx = xctr + rx + cos(ang) * sf
```

or simply

```
new_vx = vx + sf * cos(ang)
```

Same modification is needed for new_vy.

In addition, real buffer zone should be smooth near each vertex of polygon. However, you don't have this option in code.

If you want implement smoothing than you need create two new vertices for each polygon vertex and connect them with arc. These vertices should be placed on distance sf from original vertex in direction of normal vector for edge incident to polygon vertex.

Comment: How would you modify it to take into account a fixed distance and not a scale factor? In particular for a convex polygon like vx = [ 2 4 6 4 2]; %  polygon vertices
vy = [ 2 4 3 2.7 2];